# cos$^{-1}$ and units

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

So I got this problem:

So let $\triangle ABC$ be a right triangle at vertex $A$ such that $BC=2AB$. Find $\angle{ACB}$

So I found that $\cos(\angle ABC)=\frac{1}{2}$

But when I want to find $\angle ABC$, should I do $\cos^{-1}$ in radians, or degrees ?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/731274/let-abc-be-a-right-triangle-at-a-such-that-bc-2ab-find-the-angle-hatacb

Comment: Depends on what units you want to use for your angle of course. Mathematically, it's all the same, the degree is just another name for this number: ${}^\circ=\frac{\pi}{180}$ and you either choose to leave it symbollic and write $45^\circ$ or multiply and get a pure number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\cos(60^\circ) = \cos(\pi/3) = \frac 12$$

Since we are speaking of the angle of a triangle, we can narrow the solutions to $\cos^{-1}(\angle ABC)$:
We can express  $\cos^{-1}(\angle ABC)$ in either degrees ($60^\circ$) or in radians $\left(\dfrac \pi 3\right)$.

Comment: 45° really???? d

Comment: @user138849 I missed my morning coffee! :-|

Comment: hihi :p that was right!